# Multithreading: Wrong behaviour of synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to mutli-threading in java and trying to understand the keyword **synchronization** 
I have following code:

```
class LockObject {
    int threadsGoingThrough = 0;

    synchronized void locked() {
        threadsGoingThrough++;

        try {
            wait(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }

        if (threadsGoingThrough > 1) {
            System.out.print("  !! ouups !! "); 
        }
        ;
        threadsGoingThrough--;
    }
}
```

The Thread-class:

```
class LockTester extends Thread {
    LockObject myLock;
    String message;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            myLock.locked();
            System.out.print(message);
        }
    }
}
```

My main looks like this:

```
LockObject theLock = new LockObject();
LockTester threadA = new LockTester();
threadA.myLock = theLock;
threadA.message = "A";

LockTester threadB = new LockTester();
threadB.myLock = theLock;
threadB.message = "B";

threadA.start();
threadB.start();
```

If I run this code now in two threads than it gives the following ouput:

!! ouups !! A  !! ouups !! B  !! ouups !! A  !! ouups !! B  !! ouups !! A  !! ouups !! B

The !! ouups !! should only occurs when two threads are in the synchronized method at the same time. How can this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `wait()`, which will release the lock of the monitor it's called on. It will then reacquire the lock when it wakes up (either due to timeout or the monitor being notified). If you were just trying to sleep for a second, use `Thread.sleep(1000)` which *won't* release any locks.

Comment: I just read this: while sleeping, the thread still owns synchronization locks it has acquired;
 from http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml. so it should still be synchronized.

Comment: @EuclidesMulémbwè: That's using sleep (as I suggested). The OP's code uses wait.

Comment: Many thanks, didn't know that wait() releases the lock. Now it's clear ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I was thinking about the sleep method when I read this, then he should change his method to Sleep instead of wait. :)

Answer (score 1):

`wait()` method releases the lock and gives a chance for other threads to acquire the lock and execute.

you should use `sleep()` instead of `wait()` if you want the executing thread `not to release the lock` obtained during that 1 sec time